# split a string and sort it by word length

Tags: python, string, sorting

I'm trying to create a program that asks for a string and then sorts it out by crescent order of the lengths of the words. for example:

```
my_string= Hi I am learning Python
```

the result should be:

```
I Hi am Python learning.
```

Note: the order of words with the same length doesn't matter.
this is my code so far!

```
s=raw_input('string:')
t=s.split()

print t
```

Comment: `print ' '.join(sorted(t,key=len))`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `sorted` function to sort it by length like this:

```
 >>> sorted("Hi I am learning python".split(), key=len)
 ['I', 'Hi', 'am', 'python', 'learning']
```

You can then use `" ".join` to make this into a string:

```
 >>> " ".join(sorted("Hi I am learning python".split(), key=len))
 I Hi am python learning
```

Answer (score 2):

Split, sort and join again to get your expected result.

```
my_string= 'Hi I am learning Python'
s = sorted(my_string.split(), key=lambda s: len(s))
print ' '.join(s)
```

Comment: `key` can be `len` directly, There is no need of `lambda` here.

Comment: ya, i know that. but i like writing explicit code that basically shows what is happening.